# Android NDK and its library

Tags: android-ndk

Inside the Android NDK, if  want to include the Android SDK lib of

```
   #include <android/log.h>
```

I would do the following inside the Android.mk build file

```
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

The log=log.h

So, if I want to include the Android SDK

```
      #include <android/bitmap.h>
```

I would do

```
        LOCAL_LDLIBS:=-lbitmap?
```

that's one question.  ANother is if need more includes  then I have list one by one like above for log.h and bitmap.h?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a 1:1 correspondence between header files and libraries, though in a few cases they happen to coincide.

Playing with grep seems to show that functions from `<android/bitmap.h>` are in libjnigraphics.so, which would imply

```
-ljnigraphics
```

For a complete and formal reference, view the file "STABLE-APIS.HTML" in the docs/ directory of your NDK installation, where you will find this:

```
The 'jnigraphics' Library:
--------------------------

This is a tiny library that exposes a stable, C-based, interface that allows
native code to reliably access the pixel buffers of Java bitmap objects.

To use it, include the <android/bitmap.h> header in your source code, and
and link to the jnigraphics library as in:

  LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ljnigraphics
```

Comment: So some libs are from standard Android SDK and some from NDK right?

Comment: No, none are from the SDK.  The only official way you end up with any import libraries on your development machine is if you install the NDK.  Parts of the NDK provide a native analog to (or wrappers of) SDK functionality, but they are part of the NDK, not the SDK.